# failed to correct : this error SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```py
most_rated = pd.DataFrame(["135085","132825","135032","135052","132834"], index=np.arange(5), columns['placeID'])
```

This code is not working, instead showing this error.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: In Python you cannot have positional arguments (passed by position in parameter list) after a keyword argument (passed by name like `index=np.arange(5)`). You probably want to use `columns=['placeID']`.

Comment: @quamrana, syntax errors don't show a traceback.  It's clear where the problem  It's in the arguments to the is `pd.DataFrame` call.

Comment: I get an error traceback when I make a deliberate syntax error. Eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66093201). Plus a caret to show where the error is. What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
most_rated = pd.DataFrame({"135085","132825","135032","135052","132834"}, index=np.arange(5), columns=["placeID"])
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you've got a `keyword` argument, that is, one that starts with `arg_name=` before a `positional` argument - that is, one that doesn't start with a `arg_name=`. In this case, it's that you have `index=np.arange(5)` before the final argument, `columns['placeID']`. You need to specify whichever `positional` arguments you want before ANY `keyword` arguments.